# RabbitMQ.Client connection failed to cluster on a single machine

Tags: .net, rabbitmq

I created RabbitMQ cluster on a single machine. The cluster contains two nodes: "rabbit1@machineName.local:6001" and "rabbit2@machineName.local:6002".
But I failed to create factory connection when HostName is "machineName.local" (not localhost).

This is my code:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();

factory.UserName = "guest";
factory.Password = "guest";
factory.HostName = "localhost";
factory.VirtualHost = "/";
factory.Port = 6001;

Byte[] body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("My first msg to cluster!");

using(var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
{
  using(var channel = connection.CreateModel())
  {
    channel.QueueDeclare("Tests", false, false, false, null);
    channel.BasicPublish("", "Tests", true, null, body);
  }
}
```

An edition I don't understand how I can create connection to cluster and not to specific node in cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a tcp proxy before your rabbitmq cluster. Client connect proxy and proxy connect to every nodes of the cluster.